# How many zig-zag sequences are there for a given length?

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics

A sequence is defined as a zig-zag sequence if every even-numbered "spot" is greater than the one before it and every odd numbered spot is less than the one spot before it. Also, a sequence must use every number from 1 to its size once in a sequence (no repeats).

For example:
${1,3,2,5,4}$ is a zig-zag sequence of length $5$.
${1,4,2,3}$ is a zig-zag of length $4$.

My question is, for any $n$, what is the number of possible zig-zag sequences of length $n$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation ... have you looked here ?

Comment: So with the link provided by @DonaldSplutterwit , the answer is "Euler's numbers" and there is nothing more to say, or is it?